# How to split two json String

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, parsing

I have a string but **it contains two object**  like the following `{"firstName":"A","lastName":"Z"}{"firstName":"B","lastName":"Y"}`
I got this string as a response but I want to process it one by one, so how I should separate this one like `{"firstName":"A","lastName":"Z"}` and `{"firstName":"B","lastName":"Y"}`

Comment: How do you get the strings? Are they separated by a line break or a similar delimiter? Do you get one string per line?

Comment: Also, javascript or java? They are not the same.

Comment: i get this string as response in one line {"firstName":"A","lastName":"Z"}{"firstName":"B","lastName":"Y"} and in Java

Comment: @pratikpoponimb , is it not json array?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Comment: @pratikpoponimb , updated my answer, please refer below

Comment: It's not valid JSON. It's just a string that _resembles_ JSON.

Comment: @Andy it just string in json

Comment: Valid JSON would be `[{"firstName":"A","lastName":"Z"},{"firstName":"B","lastName":"Y"}]`.

Comment: @pratikpoponimb - this is not json

Comment: @Andy Yes you are right but i got response from server {"firstName":"A","lastName":"Z"}{"firstName":"B","lastName":"Y"}

Comment: @ScaryWombat  Yes

Comment: Essentially you just need to split the string, and process each segment as if it were a valid JSON object.  What you have isn't valid as an object or an array.

One way to do it is split the string on "}{" which isn't a valid JSON sequence, and shouldn't appear anywhere else.  Assuming there are no other new lines in the string, something like this should do the job...

  
   `String[] objects = inputString.replaceAll("\\}\\{","\\}\n\\{").split("\n");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Object mapper = new ObjectMapper();   
 List<YourClass> ls= ((ObjectMapper) mapper).readValue(
                    "[{"firstName":"A","lastName":"Z"},{"firstName":"B","lastName":"Y"}]",
                    new TypeReference<List<YourClass>>() {
                    });
//process list.
```

`YourClass` is mapping class of json input. Hope this is what you are looking for.

Edit:

As your input is received in  `{"firstName":"A","lastName":"Z"}{"firstName":"B","lastName":"Y"}` fashion, then

```
String input = "{\"firstName\":\"A\",\"lastName\":\"Z\"}{\"firstName\":\"B\",\"lastName\":\"Y\"}";

String array[] = input.split("(?=\\{)|(?<=\\})");

System.out.println(array[0]);
System.out.println(array[1]);
```

Output:

```
{"firstName":"A","lastName":"Z"}
{"firstName":"B","lastName":"Y"}
```

Comment: in array[] i got [{"firstName":"A","lastName":"Z"},  , {"firstName":"B","lastName":"Y"}]      in array[0] i got {"firstName":"A","lastName":"Z"}  and array[1] i got blank and array[2] i got {"firstName":"B","lastName":"Y"}

Comment: Because you have extra `, ` in your input, can you please see what happens without it?

Comment: @Ashish Patil sure

Comment: if i want array[1]= {"firstName":"B","lastName":"Y"}  for that what should i do

Comment: It means, your input is quite malformed & you have extra blank `,` within it. like `{"firstName":"A","lastName":"Z"}, , {"firstName":"B","lastName":"Y"} `.  If you are receiving such malformed input, then that would be problem & you will receive even some other characters in between. 

Best you can do is ignore if array's element is blank & move on to next element.